# updateEntity["new_totalsum"] = new CrmMoney(calculatedvalue);

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I can not update the webform. To bee updated I have to push the save button two times. I´ve tried with DynamicEntity entity = (DynamicEntity)context.PreEntityImages["PreCalculate"];        DynamicEntity updateEntity = (DynamicEntity)context.InputParameters.Properties["Target"];
... updateEntity["new_totalsum"] = new CrmMoney(calculatedvalue); The problem is it will not bee updated the first time I push the save button. I have registred the image PreCalculate as Preimage and Message: Update; Eventing Pipeline Stage of Excecution: Pre Stage; Execution Mode : Syncronous
 What´s wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the modified record back into the Target when you're done, so your changed values will be used when writing the record to the database. At the end of your plugin's `Execute()` method, do

```
context.InputParameters[ParameterName.Target] = updateEntity;
```

Comment: Thank You, I tried with: updateEntity["new_ersttniningtotalt"] = new CrmMoney(totalsum); context.InputParameters[ParameterName.Target] = updateEntity; ... But it´s still the same problem. The database is updated but not the webform. If I first save the changes will not be viewed. I I save a second time the changes will be viewed in the form -not the first time.

Comment: There is an example for a Pre-plugin that modifies the triggering record in the SDK: crmsdk4\server\fullsample\pluginpreaccount\cs\preaccountpluginsample.cs

Comment: thanks, it still the same problem... still not update the webform the first time i save. I have to save two times.... I don´t have any problem to update the database. It worcs perfect. the problem is it will not update the webform the first time I push "save button". it´s really annoying.... :-(